# ggplot2 line plot dotted lines and arrows

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a lines plot.
I would like to obtain a points joined by lines plot.
I would like to have a different line type (dashed or not) based on the method (MET) and different colour line based on the variable (Var). I have observations in 4 times (MD): cd, 15, 30, 45.

I would like to add an arrow from left to right.

Here's my database:

```
> gra
   id MD        val  MET      Var
1   1 cd   0.000000 1-KM   LRT_DM
2   2 cd   0.000000  CIF   LRT_DM
3   3 15  14.740000 1-KM   LRT_DM
4   4 15  17.050000  CIF   LRT_DM
5   5 30  34.740000 1-KM   LRT_DM
6   6 30  35.230000  CIF   LRT_DM
7   7 45  55.790000 1-KM   LRT_DM
8   8 45  54.550000  CIF   LRT_DM
9   1 cd   0.000000 1-KM  LRT_HTN
10  2 cd   0.000000  CIF  LRT_HTN
11  3 15   6.321839 1-KM  LRT_HTN
12  4 15   6.024096  CIF  LRT_HTN
13  5 30  13.793103 1-KM  LRT_HTN
14  6 30  12.650602  CIF  LRT_HTN
15  7 45  36.781609 1-KM  LRT_HTN
16  8 45  37.951807  CIF  LRT_HTN
17  1 cd   0.000000 1-KM  LGIT_DM
18  2 cd   0.000000  CIF  LGIT_DM
19  3 15  16.270784 1-KM  LGIT_DM
20  4 15  16.206483  CIF  LGIT_DM
21  5 30  33.847981 1-KM  LGIT_DM
22  6 30  33.253301  CIF  LGIT_DM
23  7 45  50.831354 1-KM  LGIT_DM
24  8 45  50.060024  CIF  LGIT_DM
25  1 cd   0.000000 1-KM LGIT_HTN
26  2 cd   0.000000  CIF LGIT_HTN
27  3 15   5.714286 1-KM LGIT_HTN
28  4 15   5.714286  CIF LGIT_HTN
29  5 30  12.380952 1-KM LGIT_HTN
30  6 30  12.380952  CIF LGIT_HTN
31  7 45  36.190476 1-KM LGIT_HTN
32  8 45  36.190476  CIF LGIT_HTN
33  1 cd   0.000000 1-KM  LGITHTN
34  2 cd   0.000000  CIF  LGITHTN
35  3 15  15.217391 1-KM  LGITHTN
36  4 15  15.217391  CIF  LGITHTN
37  5 30  45.652174 1-KM  LGITHTN
38  6 30  45.652174  CIF  LGITHTN
39  7 45 117.391304 1-KM  LGITHTN
40  8 45 117.391304  CIF  LGITHTN
41  1 cd   0.000000 1-KM  LGUT_DM
42  2 cd   0.000000  CIF  LGUT_DM
43  3 15  16.470588 1-KM  LGUT_DM
44  4 15  16.867470  CIF  LGUT_DM
45  5 30  34.117647 1-KM  LGUT_DM
46  6 30  33.734940  CIF  LGUT_DM
47  7 45  51.764706 1-KM  LGUT_DM
48  8 45  50.602410  CIF  LGUT_DM
49  1 cd   0.000000 1-KM LGUT_HTN
50  2 cd   0.000000  CIF LGUT_HTN
51  3 15   5.714286 1-KM LGUT_HTN
52  4 15   5.714286  CIF LGUT_HTN
53  5 30  12.380952 1-KM LGUT_HTN
54  6 30  12.380952  CIF LGUT_HTN
55  7 45  36.190476 1-KM LGUT_HTN
56  8 45  36.190476  CIF LGUT_HTN
```

Here's my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
gra$MD<-factor(gra$MD, levels=c("cd", "15", "30", "45"))
gra$MET<-factor(gra$MET, levels=c("1-KM", "CIF"))
gra$Var<-factor(gra$Var, levels=c("LRT_DM", "LRT_HTN","LGIT_DM",    "LGIT_HTN", "LGITHTN",  "LGUT_DM"   ,"LGUT_HTN"))

ggplot(data=gra, aes(x = gra$MD, y = gra$val, colour = gra$Var)) +geom_line(arrow = arrow())+geom_point()
```

Here's what I obtain:
[image]

Why I don't have lines?
How can I add the dashed/non dashed option?
I've tried this:

```
ggplot(gra, aes(x = gra$MD, y = gra$val, colour = gra$Var, group= gra$MET)) + geom_line(aes(linetype=gra$MET))+geom_point()
```

but it doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: First rule of ggplot is you dont need to specify the dataframe in all of your aesthetic mappings. `aes(x = MD, y = val, color = Var, ...)` is enough.

Comment: Please revise how ggplot2 syntax differs from what we're used from R. There is no directly specifying variable content in aes. You should just have an unquoted column name in its place. Regarding your first question, why are you using arrow function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map `linetype` to `MET`.

Your main problem is that you are trying to create a line plot for a discrete X scale. If you still want to retain "cd" as a label on the x axis, you can do something like this.

```
ggplot(gra, aes(x = as.integer(MD), y = val, colour = Var, linetype = MET)) +
  geom_line(arrow = arrow()) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = levels(gra$MD))
```

[image]